# What type of an induction motor is used in a single-phase non-inverter household refrigerator?

Tags: induction-motor, fluid-pump, symmetrical-components

There are many pictures with the 2-phase non-symmetrical (start winding and main winding) [on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ptcscr%22) in a single-phase non-inverter household refrigerator.

What type of squirrel cage induction motor is used in a single-phase non-inverter household refrigerator? Is it 3-phase symmetrical or 2-phase non-symmetrical or something else?

Comment: It's possible it's a reciprocating motor and not a rotating device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A household fridge is a single phase appliance and has a single phase induction motor. (Squirrel cage is not limited to single phase. )

The motor has a second winding (or tap) for starting, controlled by the little starting device on the side of the motor. Google for Refrigerator Starter Relay with the type nr on your model. Here is some info for the Danfoss 103N0050, see e.g. [here](https://manualzz.com/doc/63447577/danfoss-e-ptc-starter-electronically-controlled-ptc-start...). But this does show you that the motor has two similar windings, one for normal running, and the other just for the start.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for information. It's title is Danfoss Electronically controlled PTC Starting Device. It can be found by this title at the internet. But I search more detailed information about motors. Can be the internal protection about 5 ohms?

Comment: @Imyaf there is a lot of info on motors. I just would not look for Refrigerator motors, but for e.g. Induction Motors. But I believe I answered your original question on the number of phases, which is one.